# csrfToken: reget without logout user

Tags: 7, services, csrf

I have a site where I use AngularJS to connect to Services module paths.

Now, we know that I need to send (for every put connection) the CSRF token into headers request, and this token is linked to user's session id.

My problem is that some users are currently logged into the system for Drupal (I can see all content for authenticated users ) but when I send a PUT request, Drupal return me the error of invalid CSRF token.

So, how can I retrieve a new CSRF token without logout the user ?

M.

Answer (score 1):

To get the CSRF Token, do a GET on:

```
?q=services/session/token
```

Please note that 'services', is not the path to your endpoint, its a built in path provided by the Services module.

After grabbing the token, you then pass the token along in the header for any POST, PUT, and DELETE requests from authenticated users:

```
X-CSRF-Token=abcdefg123456789
```

[jDrupal](http://jdrupal.org) may be of use in this scenario as well, it's a JavaScript API for the Drupal Services module

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [jdrupal.js](http://jdrupal.easystreet3.com/7/docs/Introduction) to perform number of operation on Drupal site using services module. Add npm install jdrupal. It will directly retrieve a new CSRF token without logout the user.